# STM32F4 I2C Acknowledge Failure

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32

I've been trying to use my 32kb EEPROM. When i use code with this way;

program is waiting in `while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0002));` line of `I2C_Read_Data_Pro` function. After i add a little delay between `I2C_Write_Data_Pro` and `I2C_Read_Data_Pro`,program is working. What am i missing ?

```
int main(){

unsigned char EEPROM_DATA;

McuConfig();                                                                            // Islemci hiz ayari = 168 Mhz 
SysTickBaslat();                                                                    // 0.5 ms'de bir kesme olusacak sekilde ayarlandi
Delay(100);
I2C_Init();                                                                             // I2C Init Edildi
LCD_Init();                                                                             // LCD Init Edildi
I2C_Write_Data_Pro(0x50,_I2C_DEVICE_2BYTE_CHIP_IN_ADD_SIZE,0x01,'B');
I2C_Read_Data_Pro (0x50,_I2C_DEVICE_2BYTE_CHIP_IN_ADD_SIZE,0x01,&EEPROM_DATA);
while(1){
    LCD_Write(LCD_ADDR,"Hello\nNoob:)");
    Delay(1000);
    LCD_Write(LCD_ADDR,"STM32F4\nDiscovery");
    Delay(1000);
}
}
```

Write Function:

```
void I2C_Write_Data_Pro(unsigned char Add,unsigned char ChipInsideAddSize, unsigned int ChipInsideAdd ,unsigned char Data){

if((ChipInsideAddSize == _I2C_DEVICE_1BYTE_CHIP_IN_ADD_SIZE ) && (ChipInsideAdd > 255)){        // Hatali Cip Üzeri Adres Degeri Girilmisse
                                                                                                                                                                                        // Engelle
}
else{
    I2C2->CR1 |= (1UL << 8);                                                                        // Start Bit Gönder.
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0001));                                                               // START Sarti Olusmasi Icin Bekle (SB=1)
    I2C2->DR = (Add << 1);                                                                          // 7 Bit Address + Slave Yazma Istegi(0) 
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0002));                                                               // Adres Gönderilen Kadar Bekle (ADDR = 1)
    while(!(I2C2->SR2 & 0x0001));                                                           // MSL
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0080));                                                               // Data Register'in Bos Olamsini Bekle.(TXE = 1)
    I2C2->DR = (ChipInsideAdd & 0x000F);                                                // Yazma Yapilacak Cihazin Üzerindeki Adresin 1. Byte'i Gönderiliyor
    if(ChipInsideAddSize == _I2C_DEVICE_2BYTE_CHIP_IN_ADD_SIZE){// Eger Yazma Yapilacak Cihazin Üzerindeki Adres Uzunlugu 2 Byte'lik ise
        while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0080));                                                           // Data Register'in Bos Olamsini Bekle.(TXE = 1)
        I2C2->DR = ((ChipInsideAdd & 0x00F0)>>4);                                   // Yazma Yapilacak Cihazin Üzerindeki Adresin 2. Byte'i Gönderiliyor
    }
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0080));                                                               // Data Register'in Bos Olamsini Bekle.(TXE = 1)
    I2C2->DR = Data;                                                                                        // Cihaz Üzerindeki Adrese Yazma Islemi Gerceklestiriliyor.
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0080));                                                               // Data Register'in Bos Olamsini Bekle.(TXE = 1)
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0004));                                                               // Data ransfer Edilene Kadar Bekle.(BTF = 1)
    I2C2->CR1 |= (1UL << 9);                                                                        // Stop Bit Gönder
}

}
```

Read Function:

```
void I2C_Read_Data_Pro(unsigned char Add,unsigned char ChipInsideAddSize, unsigned int ChipInsideAdd ,unsigned char* IncomingData){

if((ChipInsideAddSize == _I2C_DEVICE_1BYTE_CHIP_IN_ADD_SIZE ) && (ChipInsideAdd > 255)){        // Hatali Cip Üzeri Adres Degeri Girilmisse
                                                                                                                                                                                        // Engelle
}
else{
    I2C2->CR1 |= (1UL << 8);                                                                        // Start Bit Gönder.
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0001));                                                               // START Sarti Olusmasi Icin Bekle (SB=1)
    I2C2->DR = (Add << 1);                                                                          // 7 Bit Address + Slave Yazma Istegi(0) 
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0002));                                                               // Adres Gönderilen Kadar Bekle (ADDR = 1)
    while(!(I2C2->SR2 & 0x0001));                                                           // MSL
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0080));                                                               // Data Register'in Bos Olamsini Bekle.(TXE = 1)
    I2C2->DR = (ChipInsideAdd & 0x000F);                                                // Yazma Yapilacak Cihazin Üzerindeki Adresin 1. Byte'i Gönderiliyor
    if(ChipInsideAddSize == _I2C_DEVICE_2BYTE_CHIP_IN_ADD_SIZE){// Eger Yazma Yapilacak Cihazin Üzerindeki Adres Uzunlugu 2 Byte'lik ise
        while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0080));                                                           // Data Register'in Bos Olamsini Bekle.(TXE = 1)
        I2C2->DR = ((ChipInsideAdd & 0x00F0)>>4);                                   // Yazma Yapilacak Cihazin Üzerindeki Adresin 2. Byte'i Gönderiliyor
    }
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0080));                                                               // Data Register'in Bos Olamsini Bekle.(TXE = 1)


    I2C2->CR1 |= (1UL << 8);                                                                        // Start Bit Gönder.
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0001));                                                               // START Sarti Olusmasi Icin Bekle (SB=1)
    I2C2->DR = (Add << 1) | 0x01;                                                               // 7 Bit Address + Slave Okuma Istegi(1)
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0002));                                                               // Adres Gönderilen Kadar Bekle (ADDR = 1)
    while(!(I2C2->SR2 & 0x0001));                                                           // MSL
    while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0040));                                                               // Data Gelene Kadar Bekle.(RXNE = 1)
    *IncomingData = I2C2->DR;                                                                       // Alinan Datayi Gösterilen Adrese Kaydet
    I2C2->CR1 |= (1UL << 9);                                                                        // Stop Bit Gönder
}

}
```

**Edit:**
I analyzed the bus with logic analyzer and i took this screenshot when there was no delay between write and read functions.

https://ibb.co/dLkL7J3

**Edit 2:**
Solved , problem is not the stm32.I'm using 24c32 EEPROM, so when i look the datasheet, it says that it must be at least 10ms free bus time between last stop bit and next start bit.

https://ibb.co/6m3rTPr
https://ibb.co/VQW56k9

Comment: Do not się Magic numbers

Comment: what does it look like on the scope?  is the slave trying to respond, does the host free the data line for the slave to respond?

Comment: The header file for that chip contains a struct for the I/O register blocks and the name of each register and a defined name for each bit in each register.  Strongly suggest using those definitions.  Then we have a common reference for how each bit is accessed.  Using magic numbers like `& 0x0002));` does not convey the needed information

Comment: Strongly suggest using: [I/O library](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/05/library-09-i2c-for-stm32f4xx/) for accessing the stm32f4 I2C  peripheral interface

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently and wait states were solving it (not really solving). Turned out the way I was waiting for the status flag was wrong. So make sure:
1- You are clearing the flag once it is detected
2- You are waiting for the correct bit
3- You do the above correctly
For example, I can't see where in your code you are clearing the status register bit after the  `while(!(I2C2->SR1 & 0x0002));` statement